# Do plugins/scripts exist for roughening paths in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I would like to know if any plugins or scripts that exist beyond using Illustrator's *Effect > Distort > Roughen* ? Illustrator only comes with a single roughening algorithm, and I'm trying to explore some variety.

Here is an affect I am trying to achieve,

[image: Sketches]

I don't have a Wacom tablet (maybe I should get one) and I am not interested in applying texture to fills.

Any pointers would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Not sure about filters, but if you want to *draw* rough lines, consider brushes.

Comment: Yup, I don't see why you couldn't convert all that art to brushes. Based on your cap desires, a pattern brush may work better than art brushes. Or use the Width Tool to taper ends...